# swift mailer : how to get last message (after replacement)

Tags: swiftmailer

we assume  that all variable is not empty, and it works fine. and it sended to my email. and all works fine too.

and the question, how i can get body that already replace?

before $mailer->send($message) i've already dump $message->getBody(); but the body did not replace yet ex:"test [username]"

after $mailer->send($message), i get same result.

my expectation : "test myname";

how can i get body that already replace by decorator plugin? need help.. thanks

```
$data = array('[username]'=>$content['username']);
$plugin = new Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin($data);
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setFrom($this->FROM_ADDRESS, $this->FROM_NAME)
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setBody("test [username]");

$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        if (!is_null($plugin)) {
            $mailer->registerPlugin($plugin);
        }



$mailer->send($message)
```

Note : In my email its already replace, and nothing wrong. i need the last body for my log. so, after message sended, it store to mylog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my own problem,

in Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin there are 3 methods that i think its important for this case,

1. beforeSendPerformed -> replace all token.
2. sendPerformed -> call the another method _restoreMessage.
3. _restoreMessage -> restore back the body.

how to solve :
in your new class, just get the value in sendperfomed, before it call _restoremessage, than throw the value to your new method.

in your new class that inherit Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin

```
public function sendPerformed(\Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt){
    $this->getValue = $evt->getMessage()->getBody();
    parent::sendPerformed($evt);
}

public function getFinalBody(){
    return $this->getValue;
}
```

thanks